# Python appending class attribute with numpy array type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to call a class attribute and append it to a list. Here is a simple script:

```
class class_1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.array([0, 0])

    def update(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x

cl_1 = class_1()
a = []
for i in range(3):
    y = cl_1.update()
    print(y)
    a.append(y)
print(a)  
# output:
[1 1]
[2 2]
[3 3]
[array([3, 3]), array([3, 3]), array([3, 3])]
```

but I expect `[array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([3, 3])]` as the final value of list `a`. I checked that there is no problem with python numbers:

```
class class_2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x

cl_2 = class_2()
a = []
for i in range(3):
    y = cl_2.update()
    print(y)
    a.append(y)
print(a)
#output
1
2
3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is a duplicate that has been asked a million times over (no reflection on you OP), but I can't seem to find a good hammer candidate.

Comment: Basically, notice that you are always appending a reference to the same array. The whole point of += is that it modifies in place, instead of creating a copy.

Comment: You can use `return self.x.copy()` to avoid the problem.

Comment: @DYZ. Or more cleanly, spell out `self.x = self.x + 1`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Fair enough. Depends on the context.

Comment: @MadPhysicist,  DYZ. Thanks! it solved my problem. But I still don't understand the logic behind it and couldn't find a good resource! :(

Comment: @Math-fort. I'll draft an answer. There's a bit of a subtle difference here because of numpy.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Thanks! Would you please also provide the best practice in these cases?

Comment: @Math-fort. Done. There is really no best practice here. I gave you an explanation of the logic and some possible solutions. Best practice depends on a mixture of what you think you need, what the situation calls for, and your personal aesthetic tastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Python integers, numpy arrays really allow in-place modification. With a Python integer, which is immutable, `x += 1` and `x = x + 1` have the same result. In both cases, `x` is rebound to a *new* integer object.

When you do `self.x += 1` to a numpy array, you do *not* change the reference that `self.x` points to. A new array is not allocated, but instead, every element in the internal buffer of the existing array is incremented. Note that an assignment still happens, but with the same reference as before.

To simulate the behavior of an integer in this context, explicitly write out the operation you want:

```
self.x = self.x + 1
```

In this case `self.x + 1` is an entirely new array, which can then be reassigned to `self.x` as an integer would be.

You have two options when it comes to how you want to fix your code:

1. If you are OK with creating a new array every time, and discarding the previous array, change the `update` method as shown above. In some ways this solution is cleanest because it minimizes the effects on outside references. At the same time, you might not want to create a new copy every time.
2. If you want to avoid creating unnecessary copies in most cases (or at least have control over when the copies get made), use [@DYZ's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662051/python-appending-class-attribute-with-numpy-array-type#comment90287908_51662051). Instead of `a.append(y)`, do

   ```
   a.append(y.copy())
   ```

   or alternatively, make the copy immediately:

   ```
   y = cl_2.update().copy()
   ```

**TL;DR**

One of the most common beginner pitfalls is happening here: creating a list from references to the same mutable object, and then mutating the object. All the references will end up with the last value of the object, as expected.